# sql server load data without modifying the table structure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a project of migrating an Access database to SQL Server 2008. I have successfully recreated all objects as SQL Server objects, but because the original database was still in use, some data within changed.

What's the easiest way to reload affected tables, without the table structure and relationships getting destroyed. I tried Import and Export data tool, included in the installation, but it complains about foreign keys whenever I ask it to wipe the data on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below script will allow you to generate 'create' as well as 'drop' statements for each Foreign Key constraint.

Note that I have checked this in the live environment and it is working fine. If you give it some time, you can be assured about the solution.

1. Copy the below script
2. Execute it without any change, you will get ALTER statements for each table occupying FOREIGN KEY.
3. Copy those statements and save it to another query
4. Now change the line

   ```
   --SET @action='DROP'
   ```

   To

   ```
   SET @action='DROP'
   ```
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3

   Now you have scripts to drop and create All FOREIGN KEYS.
6. Execute DROP statements that you obtained after step 4
7. After wiping data, execute ALTER Statements to create FOREIGN KEYS again.
8. Import your data.

Script

```
DECLARE @schema_name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @constraint_name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @constraint_object_id INT;
DECLARE @referenced_object_name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @is_disabled BIT;
DECLARE @is_not_for_replication BIT;
DECLARE @is_not_trusted BIT;
DECLARE @delete_referential_action TINYINT;
DECLARE @update_referential_action TINYINT;
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @tsql2 NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @fkCol SYSNAME;
DECLARE @pkCol SYSNAME;
DECLARE @col1 BIT;
DECLARE @action CHAR(6);
DECLARE @referenced_schema_name SYSNAME;

--SET @action='DROP'

DECLARE FKcursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT Object_schema_name(parent_object_id),
     Object_name(parent_object_id),
     name,
     Object_name(referenced_object_id),
     object_id,
     is_disabled,
     is_not_for_replication,
     is_not_trusted,
     delete_referential_action,
     update_referential_action,
     Object_schema_name(referenced_object_id)
  FROM   sys.foreign_keys
  ORDER  BY 1,
            2;

OPEN FKcursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @constraint_name, @referenced_object_name, @constraint_object_id, @is_disabled, @is_not_for_replication, @is_not_trusted, @delete_referential_action, @update_referential_action, @referenced_schema_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      IF @action <> 'CREATE'
        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + Quotename(@schema_name) + '.'
                + Quotename(@table_name)
                + ' DROP CONSTRAINT '
                + Quotename(@constraint_name) + ';';
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + Quotename(@schema_name) + '.'
                    + Quotename(@table_name) + CASE @is_not_trusted WHEN 0 THEN ' WITH CHECK ' ELSE ' WITH NOCHECK ' END
                    + ' ADD CONSTRAINT '
                    + Quotename(@constraint_name)
                    + ' FOREIGN KEY (';
            SET @tsql2 = '';

            DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR
              SELECT Col_name(fk.parent_object_id, fkc.parent_column_id),
                     Col_name(fk.referenced_object_id, fkc.referenced_column_id)
              FROM   sys.foreign_keys fk
                 INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                         ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
              WHERE  fkc.constraint_object_id = @constraint_object_id
              ORDER  BY fkc.constraint_column_id;

            OPEN ColumnCursor;

            SET @col1 = 1;

        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
          BEGIN
              IF ( @col1 = 1 )
                SET @col1 = 0;
              ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @tsql = @tsql + ',';
                    SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + ',';
                END;

              SET @tsql = @tsql + Quotename(@fkCol);
              SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + Quotename(@pkCol);

              FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;
          END;

        CLOSE ColumnCursor;

        DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;

        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ) REFERENCES '
                    + Quotename(@referenced_schema_name) + '.'
                    + Quotename(@referenced_object_name) + ' ('
                    + @tsql2 + ')';
        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ON UPDATE ' + CASE @update_referential_action WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION ' WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE ' WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL ' ELSE 'SET DEFAULT ' END + ' ON DELETE ' + CASE @delete_referential_action WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION ' WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE ' WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL ' ELSE 'SET DEFAULT ' END + CASE @is_not_for_replication WHEN 1 THEN ' NOT FOR REPLICATION ' ELSE '' END
                    + ';';
    END;

  PRINT @tsql;

  IF @action = 'CREATE'
    BEGIN
        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + Quotename(@schema_name) + '.'
                    + Quotename(@table_name) + CASE @is_disabled WHEN 0 THEN ' CHECK ' ELSE ' NOCHECK ' END + 'CONSTRAINT '
                    + Quotename(@constraint_name) + ';';

        PRINT @tsql;            
    END;

  FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @constraint_name, @referenced_object_name, @constraint_object_id, @is_disabled, @is_not_for_replication, @is_not_trusted, @delete_referential_action, @update_referential_action, @referenced_schema_name;
  END;

CLOSE FKcursor;

DEALLOCATE FKcursor;
```

Reference from http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/09/20/using-powershell-to-script-foreign-key-creation-statements.aspx

Comment: I just tried that and still got an error:
"Cannot truncate table '...' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY contstraint'.

Comment: I have changed the post. Check it and you can wipe data successfully.

Comment: this worked great. I was able to load the new data using the Import and Export Wizard. now lets just hope it won't mess up the table structure.

Comment: I have a question, if I delete the constraints and then run the script to get the recovery query... did I make a TERRIBLE mistake?

Comment: Then you will have to depend on backup. This is why I give the script to get the print out of queries. You can note that I am not executing the generated script though I can.

Comment: @Anoop can you just tell me how can I check the FK constraints in MS SMS. I have recovered the database from a backup to a separate database and run the script there (I needed to keep the data in my db). I've successfully put back all the constraints using the script and the backup... except for one, because I have modified one table since yesterday and when putting the constraint back was giving me an error.
So, I'm comparing that one table manually, but I'm a bit lost - I'd like to just have a look on what the constraint was in the backup and how it looks now, so I could put it back manually

Comment: First Generate Script for the same table from both new and old databases. Use the 'Compare It! 4' - http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp-setup.zip to compare the scripts. You will definitely get the changes that you made to the table in past days. Apply those changes to new database and issue is over!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. You could create the same new tables with different schema (in SQL server), maybe *staging*.
2. Copy access data to the *staging* tables, using the export/import tool
3. Use a trail version of [*Red-Gate data compare*](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to compare the staging tables to the source tables
4. Sync the data using the tool.

This will allow you to have a staging area for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Service) in order to convert data from access to your database.

You can also Import access database in new database and use [Redgate Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) tools or each other tools in order to compare data between two database and get sync data script.

Comment: I'll check out SSIS, I've heard about it but I couldn't try it out before since the service is missing from my installation.